# Domino SMTP routing messing up outbound mail

Tags: ibm-domino

We have quite an interesting problem regarding incoming and outgoing smtp mail.

Take these 2 e-mail addresses.

- jeroen.jacobs@mycompany.be => existing user in our environment
- jeroen.bla@mycompany.be => existing user, BUT "bla" is also the name of one of our foreign domains!

The first address, has no issues, as expected.

However, the second address causes us lots of problems. According to the domino manual, the smtp router will first do a lookup to see if the addresses matches with one in the Domino directory.This seems to be the case, as "jeroen.bla@mycompany.be" is defined as the primary internet address for one of our users.

However, Domino decides to ignore this fact, and decides to forward it to "jeroen@bla" (= our foreign domain)

This seems to contradicts the Domino manual, which says:

> After Domino accepts a message, the Router attempts to match the
>   recipient's Internet address to an entry in the Domino Directory. When
>   looking up the recipient in the Domino Directory, if the domain suffix
>   in the address matches an alternate Internet domain aliases defined in
>   a Global Domain document, and no Person document includes this
>   address, the Router performs a secondary lookup. In this secondary
>   lookup, the Router pairs the local part of the address with the domain
>   suffix of the primary Internet domain specified in the Global domain
>   document.

The first line is the most important one here. Since the recipients address exists, there should be no reason for Domino to try to pair it with another domain.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read [this article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21102170) about the SMTP- Parameter "SMTP_LEFT_DOT_NEVER_DOMAIN=1".
Setting this parameter will fix your problem.
EDIT: Yes I know, this article is VERY old, but it is still true... even in Domino 9

Comment: Thank you so much! this solved my issue. Who makes up notes.ini parameters like that? :p

Comment: I know what you mean... Or did you ever think that anyone in the world would need "ROUTERINIUSEMESSAGEDISABLED=1" (just another great name for a variable, nothing to do with this thread...)